# Laravel Search Reference Second Model/Collection/Table with orWhereHas?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement search functionality within my blade for my Script model. It performs fine for everything related to searching directly within the Script collection/table. However, my users also will need to be able to enter in a Patient first_name or last_name and search for the script records within the Script table that belong to the Patient being searched for. These are connected with a hasMany/belongsTo relationship. I'm trying to reference data from the Patient table in the Script results.

I've tried (with help from SO already) to implement `orWhereHas` and reference the patients table, but something with my syntax must be off.

The error messages I'm getting from trying to reference 'patients' with orWhereHas returns:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'scripts.patients_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `scripts` where exists (select * from `patients` where `scripts`.`patients_id` = `patients`.`id` and (`first_name` like %% or `last_name` like %%)))
```

This probably would work if it referenced `patient_id`, which is the column name for the patients foreign key. I don't know if there is a way to do that?

When I change `'patients'` to `'patient'`, I receive the error:

```
Call to undefined method App\Script::patient()
```

**Models**

```
Patient hasMany Script
Script belongsTo Patient          (patient_id)
```

**Script Blade**

```
{{ Form::text('search', $search, ['class' => 'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder' => 'Search Scripts...']) }}
{{Form::submit('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'])}}
```

**ScriptController**

```
$search = $request->search;
$patients = Patient::all();
$scripts = Script::
    when($search, function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query
                ->where('prescribe_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('efax_reference', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('efax_confirmation', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            });
        })
        ->orWhereHas('patients', function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })
        ->paginate(25);
```

I expect that if someone searches for a patient name within the search input on the Scripts table/model, they are able to cross-reference the Patients table/model and display the Scripts records that are foreign_key'ed to those Patients.

**EDIT:**

**Patient model**

```
// One Patient has Many Scripts relationship
public function scripts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Script');
}
```

**Script model**

```
// Many Scripts to One Patient relationship
public function patients() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');
}
```

Comment: Please check your App\\Script model. Seems like you have typo ```patients_id``` with ```s``` there.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria `public function patients() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');}` . No mention of `patients_id`

Comment: Can you share your relations on both App\\Patient and App\\Script ?

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria I updated the original post with script/patient relationship models

Comment: Can you try get one sample data and test the relationship. Eg:  ```dd(Script::find(1)->patients);```. Also, you should be using relation ```patient()``` only without plural since script only have 1 patient.

Comment: I think Adlan has the right idea - Laravel is likely employing it's auto-plural search for the key with patients because you named the belongs to as a plural.  Change the name to patient() and test.

Comment: @Watercayman that was the solution - doesn't seem to have affected anything else that I can see so far. Thanks so much to you and Adlan